# Request timed out iPhone to Mac localhost using MAMP

Tags: ios, iphone, macos, swift, mamp

I am trying to connect to my localhost on my macbook with my phone plugged in. I have an iPhone 5s.

I have tried using:

```
var url:NSURL = NSURL.URLWithString("http://192.168.0.108/laravel/roadi/public/login")
var url:NSURL = NSURL.URLWithString("http://localhost/laravel/roadi/public/login")
var url:NSURL = NSURL.URLWithString("http://josh.local/laravel/roadi/public/login")
```

But all give me the error "The request timed out"
I have tried deactivating my firewall as well.

What is going wrong, / how can I fix this? The the `localhost` and `josh.local` work perfectly in the simulator.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

On simulator you are running on same machine as Mac, that's why the localhost will work. 
On iPhone you need to use ip address of your Mac. If you are connected to the same network, you can try to find local address of Mac and use it:

http://www.wikihow.com/Find-Your-IP-Address-on-a-Mac

If you are not connected to the same network, you could try using public ip address, type in google "my ip address". But this may change frequently (if you have dynamic ip address)

Comment: But before I updated my OS I had other projects on my mac, and all those worked fine using `localhost`?

Comment: Not sure how it is possible, as localhost is special name for "this device in network". do you have mac and iphone connected to same wifi?

Comment: Not to the wifi, it is connected to the same router yes, but the iPhone is plugged into my mac for testing

Comment: by plugging device don't think it shares the internet. On device you have wifi or 3g, with wifi on, mac and device might be in same network, and thus you can use local addresses to find mac.